# How can I say a String matches my pattern

Tags: java, regex

how can I say that is my String match with this pattern: (install OS #name #version) which name and version can be any String without white space.

Comment: `install\s+OS\s+\W+\S+\S+` if the the parens and hashes aren't actually part of the pattern, or `\(install\s+OS\s+#\S+\s+#\S\)` if they are.

Comment: public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String command;
        do{
            command = in.next();
        }while (!(command.matches("install\\s+OS\\s+\\S+\\S+")));
    }

Comment: it doesn't work in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can use following Code:

```
    // assuming parenthesis an sharp are pattern included:
    String s = "(install OS #testname #testversion)";
    if (s.matches("\\(install\\sOS\\s#\\S+\\s#\\S+\\)")) {
        String[] splitted = s.split("\\s");
        String name = splitted[2].replace("#", "");
        String version = splitted[3].replace(")", "").replace("#", "");
        System.out.println("name: " + name);
        System.out.println("version: " + version);
    }
    // assuming parenthesis an sharp are both not pattern included:
    s = "install OS testname2 testversion2";
    if (s.matches("install\\sOS\\s\\S+\\s\\S+")) {
        String[] splitted = s.split("\\s");
        String name = splitted[2];
        String version = splitted[3];
        System.out.println("name: " + name);
        System.out.println("version: " + version);
    }
```

(if you need to allow mutliple whitespaces between parts, you have replace in both, split regex and match regex, \s with \s+)